# configuring the word boundary for word-wrap

Tags: wrapping

Is there a way to configure the word boundary character used for `word-wrap` like `breakat` option of vim? The documentation says "When word-wrapping is on, continuation lines are wrapped at the space or tab character nearest to the right window edge". Wrapping at whitespace looks ugly when the text contains a long url.

Comment: There is no user-option to alter the behavior of Emacs wrapping words at whitespace when the variable `word-wrap` is non-nil.  This is built directly into the display engine within `xdisp.c`.  If anyone is interested in seeing some of the code responsible for this behavior, grep for things such as `word_wrap`, `line_wrap`, `IT_DISPLAYING_WHITESPACE`, and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. I modified the condition in `IT_DISPLAYING_WHITESPACE` to `strchr(" \t!@*-+;:,./?", it->c)` and it works as expected.